# What does the bar above a pin name in a datasheet mean?

Tags: datasheet

This Serial Communications Controller from Zilog lists a few of its pins with a bar above the name. What does this bar mean?

From a schematic I have been looking it seems a few of these are inactive when high and active when low?

[image: Zillog SCC]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As you surmise, it means that the function the pin name implies is active when low.

For example, /INT is low to trigger an interrupt and /WR is low to indicate a write.

Comment: I'm surprised you didn't use the word "inverted". Basically, it means "not". While WR would mean the pin denotes that writing has been enabled when it is held high, /WR means that writing has been enabled when it is held low. Essentially an inversion. Or you could reinvert it by including a NOT gate in front of it. Not that you'd want to do that, just that it helps to explain it.

Answer (score 1):

It usually means an active low pin.

Comment: "usually"? When is it otherwise? :)

Comment: When technical writers don't follow established standards.

Comment: When technical writers use Microsoft Word and can't place an overheat without great gnashing of teeth, they will use a trailing \, *, or append _b. It is horrible to read.

Comment: Sometimes we stick a lower-case n at the front or back, unfortunately netlists don't handle over bars very well.

Comment: Well, you can't please everyone.

Comment: Unfortunately it is normally only schematic programs that can place an over-bar, and know what they means. The 'font' standards allow for such an object, but no one else has adopted it, not even EE.SE.

Comment: Sometimes a tilde is used like this  ~EN

Comment: [some use tilde as inverted input](http://kicad-pcb.org/libraries/klc/#S4.7), but Arduino prominently marks PWM inputs with tilde to add on confusion. Probably based on fact that ~ looks like PWM signal.